# A right triangle and a point inside that divides it into three equal areas

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

$ABC$ is a right-angled triangle ($\measuredangle ACB=90^\circ$). Point $O$ is inside the triangle such that $S_{ABO}=S_{BOC}=S_{AOC}$. If $AO^2+BO^2=k^2,k>0$, find $CO$.
[image]

The most intuitive thing is to note that $AO^2+BO^2=k^2$ is part of the cosine rule for triangle $AOB$ and the side $AB:$ $$AB^2=c^2=AO^2+BO^2-2AO.BO\cos\measuredangle AOB\\ =k^2-2AO.BO\cos\measuredangle AOB$$ From here if we can tell what $2AO.BO\cos\measuredangle AOB$ is in terms of $k$, we have found the hypotenuse of the triangle (with the given parameter). I wasn't able to figure out how this can done.

Something else that came into my mind: does the equality of the areas mean that $O$ is the centroid of the triangle? If so, can some solve the problem without using that fact?

Comment: Yes it does mean that $O$ is the centroid of the triangle…

Comment: Have you tried experimenting with geogebra, which calculates Surfaces?

Comment: Ratio of areas and centroids are affine invariants. Thus, any triangle is affinely an equilateral triangle whose center is its centroid. Sadly, length ratios are **not** affine invariants unless the lines are parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $G$ is the centroid of triangle $ABC$, and produce $CG$ to meet $AB$ at its midpoint $M$: the area of triangle $CMB$ is $1/2$ the area of triangle $ABC$, because base $MB$ is $1/2$ of base $AB$ and the altitude is the same. For the same reason the area of triangle $CGB$ is $2/3$ the area of triangle $CMB$, because $CM=2/3\,CB$. Hence:
$$
Area_{CGB}={2\over3}Area_{CMB}={2\over3}\cdot{1\over2}Area_{ABC}
={1\over3}Area_{ABC}
$$
and the same reasoning can be repeated for triangles $AGB$ and $CGA$. It follows that point $O$ in your problem is the centroid of $ABC$ and its distance from every vertex is $2/3$ of the corresponding median.

By Pythagoras theorem we then have:
$$
\left({3\over2}OB\right)^2=\left({1\over2}AC\right)^2+BC^2\\
\left({3\over2}OA\right)^2=\left({1\over2}BC\right)^2+AC^2\\
$$
Adding these equalities we thus get:
$$
{9\over4}(OA^2+OB^2)={5\over4}(AC^2+BC^2)
$$
and finally:
$$
k^2=OA^2+OB^2=
{5\over9}(AC^2+BC^2)={5\over9}AB^2
={5\over9}\left({3}OC\right)^2={5}OC^2,
$$
where I also used that hypotenuse $AB$ is twice the corresponding median and thus $3OC$.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Can you clarify for me how can we show that $O$ is the centroid of the triangle?

Comment: @KaloyanK. I edited my answer to include a standard geometrical proof. See also a comment below the other answer for a different proof.

Answer (score 2):

As @DavidQuinn noted, point $O$ is the centroid of the right triangle.

If we place $C$ at $(0,0)$ and $B$ at $(a, 0)$ and $A$ at $(0,b)$, then

$O = \dfrac{1}{3} (a, b )  $

Therefore

$OA^2 + OB^2 + OC^2 = \dfrac{1}{9} \bigg( a^2 + b^2 + 4 a^2 + b^2 + a^2 + 4 b^2 \bigg) = \dfrac{1}{9} ( 6 ) (a^2 + b^2 ) = \dfrac{2}{3} (a^2 + b^2) $

It follows that

$OC^2 = \dfrac{2}{3}(a^2 + b^2) - k^2$

Now, as noted by @LiKwokKeung below, we have that

$OC = \dfrac{1}{3} c $

from which $ a^2 + b^2 = c^2 = 9 OC^2$, hence

$ OC^2 = \dfrac{2}{3} (9 OC^2) - k^2 $

And finally,

$ OC^2 = \dfrac{k^2}{5} $

i.e.

$ OC = \dfrac{k}{\sqrt{5}} $

Comment: O is the centroid. Why ?

Comment: If you start from an equilateral triangle, you can transform it into any other triangle by a linear transformation.  The centroid of the equilateral triangle will be mapped into the centroid of the transformed triangle (this is straight forward to prove), and in addition the ratio of the areas in the original triangle will be mapped into the same ratio of areas in the transformed triangle, which can be proven using the determinant of the $2 \times 2$ matrix whose columns are the difference between the coordinates:  $B-A$ and $C - A$.

Comment: @Nathalieissweetandawesome  Using $\frac{3OC}{2}=\frac{c}{2}$, the final answer can be written in terms of $k$ only.

Comment: @LiKwokKeung Thank you I've added your comment to improve my answer.